# Why isn't a null pointer exception checked at compile time, e.g. when iterating a null collection in Java instead of a run time exception?

Tags: java, collections

Whenever I'm iterating a `Collection` in Java which is `null`, it's throwing a `NullPointerException` at run time. Why isn't there a compile time check?

e.g here:

```
List<String> list = null;
for (String str : list) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: In general it can't be detected at compile-time, so there has to be a runtime exception, so it isn't worth checking for the few cases that can be caught at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I think of it is

RuntimeExceptions are thrown for things that are preventable.

For example, NullPointerExceptions can always be avoided and are therefore unchecked exceptions.

So, the compiler doesn't do that. Although tools like Intellij IDE or SonarLint will show you a warning saying that it may throw a NullPointerException.

Anyway, a programmer should be aware whether or not something will throw a NullPointerException or not.